# Getting unwanted where clause in query in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

I am writing a query to fetch records through `createQuery()`. Upon checking the `SQL`, there is a `where` clause like this:

`` WHERE ( `sys_category`.`pid` IN ( 47, 0 ) ) ``

Here `47` is the `sys_folder` ID in which my records are saved but the problem is that the categories are stored in another folder with a different ID so it cannot find the `47` ID in the `sys_category` table. How can I override/fix this `where` clause?

Also, is it necessary that the categories I am associating my records with, need to be in the same folder as the records? if so why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `$defaultQuerySettings` to change the PID it searches on.

Either you can set it in the `instantiateObject()` method and it will be used for every query or you can set it in your findBy method.

```
$querySettings = $this->objectManager->get(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Typo3QuerySettings::class);
// here you can search on all PIDs
$querySettings->setRespectStoragePage(false);
// here you can set special PIDs
$querySettings->setStoragePageIds([12, 15, 38]);

// Set the setting
$this->setDefaultQuerySettings($querySettings);
```

Comment: the `$this` in the context is the repository? and should I use this before I create the query object?

Comment: in the createQuery method there is already an assignment like this ```if ($this->defaultQuerySettings !== null) {
            $query->setQuerySettings(clone $this->defaultQuerySettings);
        }```

Comment: You need this before executing the query, not before creating it. For better reading I would put this code on the top of your repository method.

Comment: This assignment is weird and prevents any change to the query settings. I would strongly recommend to remove this.

Comment: I used it like this ```$query->setQuerySettings($querySettings);``` and it worked. Thanks